# When debugging python code, Chinese variables are displayed as Unicode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When debugging Python code, Chinese variables are displayed as Unicode.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to clarify your problem

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. But this is a nice site: [link](http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx) to encode and decode strings.

Comment: d = '我的世界'
but d show '\xe6\x88……', should show "我的世界".

Comment: This may be a problem with your editor. Try looking at the code in Idle, which understands Unicode.

Comment: Is this using the current or experimental debugger?